# How can I test Customer Chat Plugin (beta) in localhost?

Tags: facebook

I'm trying use [Customer Chat Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin/) in my website (is not a Wordpress), but to test if the plugins is working I need deploy it many times.

Any way to test in my local machine? using localhost address?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [ngrok](https://dashboard.ngrok.com/get-started). It will expose your website running in localhost to internet and will provide you https url that you can use to test the feature. Remember to add ngork provided url to whitelisted domain in your facebook page settings before you test it.

Comment: The best way so far since facebook doesn't allow whitelisting localhost

Comment: Any specific setup with ngrok that I have to do? As I've tried so far, the chat plugin couldn't show up on my page. The domain generated by ngrok is added to the whitelist on the chatbot configuration.

Comment: @Carr We do not need any specific setup for ngrok. It should automatically forward the port to web and reveal url for you. Did you also try using `https` url in the facebook's configuration page? Or perhaps maybe some misconfiguration in plugin/app itself?

Answer (score -1):

didn't test it, but you could setup hosts file to serve your page on fake domain mapped to your local ip